# random tranche age on jupyter python

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I would like to do a random on age groups in notebook python. I wanted to know if anyone has an idea.

df_tmp['age']

Age      -------------------------->                 after rand (expected results)

0 - 25 ans  ----------------------->              22

26 - 30 ans   --------------------->              28

31 - 35 ans      --------------------->           33

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.random.randint(lo, hi)` is used to get a random integer `x` in the range `lo <= x < hi`.  you also need some way of turning those values into low and high values, which I'd use a dictionary for.

putting the above together we get:

```
import numpy as np

age_ranges = {
    '0 - 25 ans': (0, 25),
    '26 - 30 ans': (26, 30),
    '31 - 35 ans': (31, 35),
}

def sample_age_from_range(ar):
    lo, hi = age_ranges[ar]
    return np.random.randint(lo, hi + 1)
```

we can then apply this to some data:

```
import pandas as pd

# create some test data
df = pd.Series([
    '0 - 25 ans',
    '26 - 30 ans',
    '31 - 35 ans',
], name='age').to_frame()

df['age2'] = df['age'].apply(sample_age_from_range)
```

which gives me:

```
           age  age2
0   0 - 25 ans     4
1  26 - 30 ans    29
2  31 - 35 ans    33
```